# Fitting table to half of the page using template

Tags: tables

Following 
[Table to fit the rest of the paper width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288768/table-to-fit-the-rest-of-the-paper-width)
[my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288768/table-to-fit-the-rest-of-the-paper-width),
I use the amcs template [amcs template](https://www.amcs.uz.zgora.pl/?action=guide)
and the following:

```
\documentclass{amcs}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c L S[table-format=0.1]*{2}{S[table-format=0.1]}}
        \toprule
        \thead{ID}  &   \thead{UCI Dataset Name} 
        &   {\thead{Samples\\(number)}}
        &   {\thead{Attributes\\(number)}} 
        &   {\thead{Classes\\(number)}}           \\
        \midrule
        DS1 & Poker Hand                          & 1025010  & 11    & 9     \\
        DS2 & SUSY                                & 5000000  & 18    & 2     \\
        DS3 & Record Linkage Comparison  Patterns & 5749132  & 9     & 2     \\
        DS4 & KDD Cup 1999                        & 4898431  & 42    & 23    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Datasets used for empirical evaluation}
    \label{table:1}
\end{table} 
 \end{document}
```

This is the result I get:
[image]
I need it to be in one column of the page. It is supposed to match into one column to the `amcs` format, like this:[image]
How can I adjust the table to fit into one page column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace first row of your table with:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}c L S[table-format=7.0]*{2}{S[table-format=2.0]}@{}}
```

Result will be something like this:

[image]

**Edit:**
Slightly better result you will obtain with:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}c L S[table-format=7.0]*{2}{S[table-format=2.0]}@{}}
    \toprule
    \thead{ID}  &   \thead{UCI Dataset Name}
    &   {\thead{Samples\\(num.)}}
    &   {\thead{Attributes\\(num.)}}
    &   {\thead{Classes\\(num.)}}           \\
    \midrule
    DS1 & Poker Hand                          & 1025010  & 11    & 9     \\
    DS2 & SUSY                                & 5000000  & 18    & 2     \\
    DS3 & Record Linkage Comparison  Patterns & 5749132  & 9     & 2     \\
    DS4 & KDD Cup 1999                        & 4898431  & 42    & 23    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Datasets used for empirical evaluation}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Or you can just use `\resizebox` like this:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
  \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    column1 & column2 & column3 & column4 \\
    \hline
    data1 & data2 & data3 & data4 \\
    \hline 
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}
```

Found it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595900/244690

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable for a fast proof ...

Comment: BTW, it is very wise to avoid using `\resizebox` when writing tables. It lead to inconsistent font size in table ...

Comment: Noted. Thank you so much. I am new to latex.